# Rails Inconsistent database results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails application where there is a request to create elements on a table and another one, waiting, that reads if such element was created or not.

Right now, I check the live Data and the waiting process never sees any new record for the table.

Any ideas how to force a reconnection or anything that will update the model reference?

The basic idea:

- One user, through a POST, is creating a record (that i can see directly on the database).
- Another piece of code, that was running before the requests, is waiting for that record, but does not find it.

I'd appreciate any insights.

Comment: Can you show the code that's waiting for the record?

Comment: Its something like this: `Entity.where(key: @key)&.last`

I do check that "@key" it's exactly what it's supposed to be.

I can't show the full code and it's quite hard to decouple from the rest. After that line, it sleeps for 15 seconds and retries until it has been 5 minutes or that query returns something.

Comment: So it's like `result = Entity.where(key: @key)&.last` ?  And (sorry for the simplistic questions but always best to cover all) this expression is within the 15 second sleep loop? Can you at least include the loop code, with the non-relevant lines removed?  Incidentally, better would be `result = Entity.find_by(key: @key)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The waiting request is probably using the ActiveRecord cache. Rails caches queries for the duration of a request, so if you run the exact same query multiple times in the same request, it will only hit the database the first time.

You can simulate this in the console:

```
Entity.cache { Entity.first; Entity.first }
```

In the logs, you'll see something like this (notice the second request says `CACHE`):

```
[2018-12-06T10:51:02.436 DEBUG (1476) #] Entity Load (4.9ms)  SELECT "entities".* FROM "entities" LIMIT 1
[2018-12-06T10:51:02.450 DEBUG (1476) #] CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "entities".* FROM "entities" LIMIT 1
```

To bypass the cache, you can use:

```
Entity.uncached { Entity.where(key: @key)&.last }
```

Using `uncached` will disable the cache inside the block, even if the enclosing scope is running inside a `cached` block.

Comment: Thanks Kelvin, thats a better soluton.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, for a running Rails application, if a running piece of code is looking for anything that has been updated by a new request, after the first began its execution, the updated data would not show, using active_record models.

The solution: Just run a raw query.

`sql = "SELECT * FROM entities WHERE key = '"+key+"' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;"
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).values`

I know it's a huge oversimplification and that there is probably an underlying problem, but it did solved it.